# Zend Framework 2 - get url segment at random position as param

Tags: php, parameters, routes, zend-framework2

If I have my routing set up like this:

```
'foo' => array (
        'type' => 'segment',
        'options' => array (
                'route' => '/:foo',                                     
                'defaults' => array (
                        'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Foo',
                        'action' => 'foo' 
                ) 
        ),
        'may_terminate' => true,
        'child_routes' => array (
                'bar' => array (
                        'type' => 'segment',
                        'options' => array (
                                'route' => '/:bar[/:someMoreData]',
                                'defaults' => array(
                                        'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Foo',
                                        'action' => 'bar'
                                )
                        ),
                        'may_terminate' => true
                )
        )
)
```

And I have URLs like this:
    http://127.0.0.1/foo/bar/someParam(123)/someOtherParam(456,789)/myParam(1,2,3)

where the order of the three (or possibly even more params) is completely random and their values, encased in brackets, can also be completely random.

How would I need to adjust my routing to access every param and its value in my Controller using `$this->params('myParam')` or similar?

Basically exactly like I would be able to using a query string:
    http://127.0.0.1/foo/bar?myParam=1,2,3&otherParam...

Or am I misunderstanding something here?

Note: I can't use query strings.

Comment: Rather than adding the data into the route, can't you use GET params instead? e.g. `http://blah/foo/bar?someParam=(123)&someOther=(456, 789)` Then you can use `$this->params()->fromQuery('someParam')`

Comment: Hey, sorry. I forgot to specify that I can't use GET params. I added that limitation to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use query params for your use case? It would be much cleaner imo.

Anyway you can use the `fromRoute()` method without any arguments to retrieve all parameters.

```
public function myAction()
{
    $params = $this->params()->fromRoute();
}
```

Comment: Query params are definitely the way forward, however the answer you've provided is incorrect `$this->params()->fromRoute()` will return all *defined* route parameters. Seeing as OP says they can be random, they're not going to be defined...

Comment: Yes you are right. I didn't read "or possibly even more params". Segmented routes don't support dynamic number of params, so there is only one solution left which is a custom route. But I can't imagine  a use case where op couldn't use query params.

Comment: The answer why I can't use query params is as simple as it is sad :/ SEO department won't allow it :/ The assumption that the params are not defined is correct. Custom routes sound like a hint in the right direction. I will go and check out that topic. Do you have experience in custom routing and can possibly elaborate on my topic?

Comment: I don't have time to work out a solution now but can give you some pointers. You must implement `RouteInterface`. Implement both `assemble` and `match` methods. You are first interested in implementing `match`. Here you can explode the path from the Request object and construct a new `RouteMatch` object on which you set the params. Next register the custom route on the route plugin manager. Finally you can use `"type" => "my-route"` in the route configuration.

Comment: Epic. I will get right on trying. I'll come back once I've put the thing together. Thx!

Comment: @BramGerritsen: What would you consider best practice when dealing with large routing configurations and complex param order: Would you say the router should simply define the route and not bother with params at all, so you can match them later from the url string manually? Or should the router extract all params and their value from the route, so you don't need to write an own parser? Basically: Is it worth it putting the time in to write a custom route or leave the routing basic and parse the url string by ourselves somewhere deeper in the code?